# Android Dagger 2 is asking for @Provides while it's there

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, dagger-2, dagger

I'm trying to implement Retrofit within my project using dagger 2 and it gives me the below error:

```
Error:(22, 10) error: com.toranj.tyke.restApi.LotteryApiInterface cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
com.toranj.tyke.restApi.LotteryApiInterface is injected at
com.toranj.tyke.ui.MainActivity.LotteryApiInterface
com.toranj.tyke.ui.MainActivity is injected at
com.toranj.tyke.dagger.components.NetworkComponent.inject(activity)
```

so here is my **LotteryApiInterface**:

```
public interface LotteryApiInterface {
    @GET("/lottery/search")
    Call<List<Lottery>> getByCriteria(@Query("q") String query);

    @GET("lottery/details")
    Call<Lottery> getById(@Query("Id") String id);
}
```

and here is the **LotteryComponent**:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = NetworkComponent.class, modules = LotteryModule.class)
public interface LotteryComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

}
```

and there goes my **LotteryModule**:

```
@Module
public class LotteryModule {

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    public LotteryApiInterface providesLotteryApiInterface(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(LotteryApiInterface.class);
    }
}
```

when I **Clean > Rebuild** the project it gives me the error even though my LotteryModule has the @Provides annotation for the object.

Probably I'm missing something in here. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Retrofit is created in my Application class as below:

```
public class TykeApp extends Application {

    private NetworkComponent networkComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        networkComponent = DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .networkModule(new     NetworkModule("http://192.168.0.3:8080"))
                .build();
    }

    public NetworkComponent getNetworkComponent() {
        return networkComponent;
    }
}
```

**NetworkComponent**:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class })
public interface NetworkComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity activity);

    Retrofit retrofit();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();
}
```

**NetworkModule:**

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    String baseUrl;

    public NetworkModule(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

    @Provides
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient httpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

and this is the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    LotteryApiInterface LotteryApiInterface;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ((TykeApp)getApplication()).getNetworkComponent().inject(this);

        LotteryComponent lotteryComponent = DaggerLotteryComponent.builder()
                .lotteryModule(new LotteryModule())
                .build();
        lotteryComponent.inject(this);
    }
}
```

When I use

```
@Inejct 
LotteryApiInterface LotteryApiInterface;
```

it throws the given error message.

Comment: And where do you create `Retrofit` itself?

Comment: Retrofit is created in Application and it's singleton and it works pretty fine. I'll update the question

Comment: Retrofit passed to that method `public LotteryApiInterface providesLotteryApiInterface(Retrofit retrofit) {` should be created with dagger

Comment: Also your actual error has to do with either `NetworkComponent` or `MainActivity`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I know. Retrofit is created fine by the Lottery component doesn't work and the error message is regarding the retrofit interface. \@Provides is added for LotteryModule but it's still asking for it

Comment: Code for `MainActivity` where you inject it and get the component, pls

Comment: @EpicPandaForce already added mate. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use *field injection* in Dagger2, then your component that you use `component.inject(this);` with needs to be able to provide ***every dependency*** that you marked with `@Inject`.

This means that in your case, you shouldn't have

```
    ((TykeApp)getApplication()).getNetworkComponent().inject(this);
```

And instead you're supposed to have

```
    LotteryComponent lotteryComponent = DaggerLotteryComponent.builder()
            .networkComponent(((TykeApp)getApplication()).getNetworkComponent())
            .lotteryModule(new LotteryModule())
            .build();
    lotteryComponent.inject(this);
```

But it's worth noting that your network module should be

```
@Module
public class NetworkModule {

    String baseUrl;

    public NetworkModule(String baseUrl) {
        this.baseUrl = baseUrl;
    }

    @Provides
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkhttpClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return client.build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(OkHttpClient httpClient) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .client(httpClient)
                .build();
    }
}
```

And your NetworkComponent should be

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = { AppModule.class, NetworkModule.class })
public interface NetworkComponent {
    Retrofit retrofit();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences();
}
```

Comment: woh... awesome, it worked. Thanks for the help. I got your point. Cheers